# Why is it possible on Android 5 (Lollipop) to directly change UI views from other threads?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Consider the following code:

```
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myTextView.setText("Some text");
    }
}.start();
```

On pre-Lollipop androids, that code causes the `CalledFromWrongThreadException` exception, but why does it work fine on Lollipop androids?

Testing environment: Genymotion emulator running Android 5.1

The code was inside the `onCreateView()` method of the `Fragment` class.

Comment: interesting. could it have something to do with the new renderthread?

Comment: no thats not possible you have to use handers or Activity.runOnUIThread()

Comment: @Sam I know how to handle it but it works on Android 5. Just test it yourself

Comment: is it works with all views or only TextView?

Comment: @Sone, it also works with `LinearLayout` where I added some views using `addView` method.

Comment: Have you looked at the source?

Comment: it works also on 4.4.4 , on a real device (moto e)

Comment: @Vaiden no I've not.

Comment: @Blackbelt But it does not work on 4.4.4, on Genymotion emulator

Comment: Just because it doesn't crash in this particular case does not mean it's a safe thing to do in general. The framework does't guard against off-UI-thread access on all methods, but you should consider that the default rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of timing, for example inserting your code in onCreate() would *not* crash the app on Samsung Galaxy S3 nor Nexus 7 2013 on Android 5.1. However, if you modify the code such that it's constantly updating the TextView:

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                SystemClock.sleep(16);
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.test)).setText(count++ + "");
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

Then it'll crash on ~18th call, when `TextView.setText(String)` inadvertently calls `View.requestLayout();` which eventually calls `ViewRootImpl.requestLayout()` that actually does check for correct thread.
This is probably done to reduce the overhead of thread checking to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

What I have noticed so far, If you create a new thread in an Activity, the code compiles and runs without and error.

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtName.setText("Some text");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

but if you create a new thread in a service or asynctask, it causes the CalledFromWrongThreadException exception.