# Able to update UI in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

As far as I know, we cannot change UI elements from doInBackground method of AsyncTask but it is not giving any exception on doing the same and changing the text of TextView.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  TextView tv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Main : " + Thread.currentThread().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new DemoAsync().execute();
  }

  class DemoAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String threadName = "Async : " + Thread.currentThread().getName();
         for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            tv.setText("Changed " + i);
        }
        return threadName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String threadName) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, threadName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   }
 }
```

I tried checking if doInBackground is running in Main thread but this is not the case either. However, on showing Toast in doInbackground, app crashes which it should. Modifying TextView should have crashed the app as well.Can someone explain this behaviour ?

P.S - Regarding the possible duplicate, I am running the code on pre lollipop so the question as well as the chosen answer does not relate to this.Also, the answer suggests that modifying the TextView will crash on later calls (18th to be precise in case of chosen answer).I have updated the code to modify TextView in a loop of 1000 iterations and it is still running fine.

Comment: this is weird, but tv variable is not even final how are you able to access it from the inner class.

Comment: This indeed is very weird, if it is in-fact happening!

Comment: What is your log output when the app crashes?

Comment: tv is an instance variable, so no need for final here!

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getName(); inside AsyncTask, what you are really trying to do ?

Comment: Please read the question guys, he wants to know WHY it DOES NOT crash, when it should!

Comment: @Sree - I am trying to get the name of the thread in which Async is running.Actually I wanted to check if it is running in the main thread or not because I am able to update the TextView but this is not the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it possible on Android 5 (Lollipop) to directly change UI views from other threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990029/why-is-it-possible-on-android-5-lollipop-to-directly-change-ui-views-from-othe)

Comment: @yaa110 - I am running the code on 4.1.1 (pre lollipop).

Comment: @amritsingh please read the accepted answer, it would occur in all versions

Answer (score 0):

You should not access the UI from `doInBackground` as stated in the [Android "Processes and Threads" documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Comment: Source? Please quote it?

Comment: Source added in my answer

Comment: @barq - But what happens if I do this ? Should it crash or not ? Why is it only crashing in case of Toast and not TextView ?

Comment: The source nowhere states that you can update UI in doInBackground(). If you search on that page - there are only 6 instances where `doInBackground()` is quoted and nowhere it states that you can update UI here.

Answer (score 0):

It is only a timing misunderstanding: at first sight it seems that `tv.setText("Changed " + i);` in the doInBackground() changes the View in the UI,

**but**

in reality when the last setText is executed the UI is not yet ready and connected with the activity, thus the last setText in the loop changes a View that is not yet in the UI.

If we delay the loop, e.g. by 10000 iterations, the UI will start and we will get **always** the exception "Only the original thread that created a hierarchy view can touch its view".

Answer (score 0):

We can update the ui from doinbackground use below function to update ui.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   Write your code here to run in UI thread
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

check out here [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

*AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.*

**Edit:** In OOP, You can access global variable from inner class. so, from this perspective, in this example, class extending AsyncTask is inner class you can access TextView tv; since execute is called in main UI thread thereby you able to modify but if it wasn't inner class you cannot access variable defined according to abstraction because doInBackground runs in another thread(not UI). In short you cannot modify UI element in doInBackground() but inner class can access widget object declared globally to change values in container as done in this question

Comment: This is not an answer, down voting this.

Comment: let me more specific, you can modify UI elements in UI thread not in background thread. yes you are correct you cannot modify UI elements in doInBaclground() since it run in background. here you declared _TextView tv;_ globally and since global objects can be accessible to inner classes it possible to modify contents. and also you are calling execute() on UI thread it is possible, to understand this completely check out official documentation.

Comment: Please quote the source with the link.

Comment: it is basic concept in OOP (inner class, global variable) about AsyncTask already given the documentation link

Comment: Is it possible to update UI inside `doInBackground()`? If so, please quote the source?

Comment: In OOP,
You can access global variable from inner class.
so, from this perspective, in this example, class extending AsyncTask is inner class you can access _TextView tv;_ since execute is called in main UI thread thereby you able to modify but if it wasn't inner class you cannot access variable defined according to abstraction because doInBackground runs in another thread(not UI).
In short you cannot modify UI element in doInBackground() but inner class can access widget object declared globally to change values in container as done in this question.

Comment: Accessing a variable and modifying its content from a different thread are two different things. If you are able to access it , doesn't necessarily mean use can modify it as well.